# How to call PlayStore outside App in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an android app.

I would like to open PlayStore from my app.
I write down the following code.

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName();
try {
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

PlayStore is called correctly, however it seems to be called inside my app.(When I push home button while the PlayStore screen appears, and then I push my app icon, the PlayStore is displayed.)

I would like to call PlayStore outside my app.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: This code works on some button click?

Comment: Yes, in onClick method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will open Playstore app.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.LaunchUrlHandlerActivity"); // package name and activity
launchIntent.setComponent(comp);
launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + YOUR_MARKET_ID));

startActivity(launchIntent);
```